# Ubuntu crashes when setting maximum resolution on external 4K monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, display-resolution, displayport, 4k-monitor, usb-c

## Problem

When attempting to set the resolution of my 4K external display to 3840x2160, the external display loses signal and moments later the entire system hangs.

The display is connected to my XPS 13 9350 Developer Edition running Ubuntu 16.04 using a USB-C to DisplayPort adapter.

## Hardware:

- Machine: Dell XPS 13 9350 (3200x1800 resolution display version)
- OS Version: Ubuntu 16.04
- Display: Dell P2415Q
- Adapters:

  - [VicTop Type C to DisplayPort Adapter](http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B01AA5TSGQ)
  - [BENFEI USB 3.1 Type C to Displayport Adapter](http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B017OVBUHO)

## Attempted Fixes

### Setting Resolution Manually

I have tried using `xrandr` to manually set the mode and refresh rate of the display. Setting it to 4K at 60Hz shows the same problems as setting it in the GUI but if I set it to **4K at 30Hz it works fine**.

Doesn't work: `xrandr --output DP1 --mode 3840x2160 -r 60.00`
Does work : `xrandr --output DP1 --mode 3840x2160 -r 29.98`

### Multiple Adapters

I have attempted using multiple different USB-C to DisplayPort adapters, both of which give the impression that they are capable of 4K resolution at 60Hz. The adapter used does not appear to make a difference to the problem.

### Kernel Update

I have updated the kernel to version 4.6 in case better support was added for the integrated Iris graphics. This does not appear to have made any difference.

I hope the steps I have taken that are documented above will help to diagnose the problem.

Comment: The usb c port is the weakest link here, I have a near identical setup on my m3800 but the display port is over thunderbolt and it works fine. One thing to check is that the monitor is in display port 1.2 mode or better. You could also try reducing the refresh by 1hz to 59khz to make it easier on the computer. You can generate modelines with CVT and apply them with xrandr Are there any specific error messages ?

Comment: The monitor is set to DisplayPort 1.2 mode according to instructions in the manual. The only actual error message I have seen is an error saying it couldn't load the display configuration file after a reboot. I will have a look at adjusting the refresh rate like you suggested.

Comment: i've seen that error before, its because the monitor didn't respond quickly enough, it takes several seconds to sync a 4k monitor.

Comment: this thread has lots of suggestions http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2301071&page=35

Comment: I can confirm exactly the same problem with the Lenovo Yoga 900 using USB-C to HDMI and DisplayPort adapters. The display is blank at 60Hz even though xrandr reports the mode is available. Reducing frequency slightly also does not work - but going down to 30Hz does work - however the latency is then horrible. I have eliminated my hardware as the problem, since booting to Windows 10 with the same adapters/display gives me rock solid 3840x2160 at 60Hz through USB-C to both HDMI and DisplayPort.

Comment: Should also mention that I am running stock Ubuntu 16.04 on the 4.4 kernel I  too have tried the 4.5 and 4.6 kernels but with no improvement.

Comment: Does your machine also have the Intel Iris 540 graphics chipset?

Comment: Its latest generation Intel Skylake - I think its Iris 520.  Here's the lshw details...

       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Sky Lake Integrated Graphics
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915_bpo latency=0

Comment: Yes here's what "About This Computer" shows:  Intel® HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2)

Comment: One more tip I just discovered.  After switching to 4K at 30Hz I had terrible latency - window drag not keeping up with mouse.  Keypress feeling laggy when typing etc.  I discovered that if I reset unity with "unity --replace" the responsiveness is a lot better - but still nothing like Windows 10 with 4K at 60Hz.

Comment: Having the same issue with the XPS 9350 and monitor Dell P2415Q (using the Plugable USB-C to DisplayPort Adapter Cable https://www.amazon.com/Plugable-DisplayPort-Chromebook-ThunderboltTM-3840x2160/dp/B01EXKDRAC/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1469101485&sr=8-2&keywords=pluggable+usb-c+dp). Upgrading the kernel to 4.6.4 or 4.7.0rc7 does not seem to solve the problem. At least after the BIOS update to 1.4.4 I was able to use it with the refresh rate of 29.98 (before it would crash the OS).

Comment: Please do not post "this affects me" or "I can confirm this" as an answer.  When you all have sufficient reputation, you will be able to comment on posts.

Comment: That's good news that 4.8+ seems to start solving this issue, I've had my P2715Q since 2015 and can't get it to work in a stable way on 16.04 on the XPS13 above 1080p@60. You're testing from this PPA? http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.8/

Answer (score 4):

Having the same issue with the XPS 9350 (QHD+, BIOS v1.4.4) and external monitor Dell P2415Q. I am using the [Plugable USB-C to DisplayPort Adapter Cable](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01EXKDRAC).

Upgrading the kernel to [v4.8-rc2](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.8-rc2/) seems to solve this problem. I am writing this post on the external monitor running at 3840x2160 60Hz.

Having said that, it is pretty unstable. It crashes often when connecting/disconnecting the adapter and there are some graphical artefacts that appear when moving the mouse and windows around.

My hope is that the final version of the kernel will iron out these issues or at least kernel 4.9 will.

UPDATE: Ubuntu (Gnome) 16.10 works great for the configuration above. No issues so far, except some monitor flickering from time to time.

Comment: Looks like Intel have provided some updated drivers in the 4.8 kernel. http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Intel-DRM-Next-Linux-4.8

Comment: According to this https://news.slashdot.org/story/16/06/09/1433229/ubuntu-1610-to-be-powered-by-linux-kernel-48, Ubuntu 16.10 will ship with kernel 4.8 so hopefully all these problems will go away in October.

Comment: I have exactly the same hardware as you (except for the monitor - mine's a P2715Q). With the 4.4 kernel, Ubuntu 16.04 just crashed when plugging in the USBC to DP adapter. I updated to kernel 4.7 and the adapter is usable up to 2560x1440 @ 60Hz, but still crashes with 4k.

Comment: @brito at the moment it seems only kernel 4.8 will solve these issues. I am using 4.8-rc7 now and it seems fairly stable. If you don't want to update you kernel to an RC, you can wait for a month till the Ubuntu 16.10 release which would come with this version (hoping it reaches stable by then).

Comment: @aramboi 4.8 is out and I just installed it fine on Ubuntu 16.04. It solves the 4k@60Hz via USBC-DP issue, _but_ now wifi is terrible with intermittent `brcmfmac` errors. Did you experience any such errors? I'll open a question about this anyway.

Comment: @brito I have the developer edition of the XPS which comes with the intel wifi chip, not the broadcom one. For me it works fine with the 4.8 kernel stable (I have issues with the wired connection though).